# ChildRepeater getting value from ParentRepeater in CodeBehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, datasource, nested-repeater

What i'm trying to do is this

```
       <asp:Repeater ID="ParentRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ItemBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_SideMenu_Guides_Medlem" runat="server">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                   </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Codebehind

```
 ParentRepeater.DataSource = CraftGuides.GetAllGroups();
 ParentRepeater.DataBind();

 protected void ItemBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs args) 
    { 
        if (args.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) 
        { 
            Repeater childRepeater = (Repeater)args.Item.FindControl("ChildRepeater"); 
            childRepeater.DataSource = CraftGuides.GetGuidesByGroupID( Insert ID from Parent Here ); 
            childRepeater.DataBind(); 
        } 
    }
```

Now, the thing is I don't know to get the ID from the parent inside the child to collect the data from the database

Comment: When you say "I don't know [how] to get the ID from the parent inside the child", are you talking about the `ParentRepeater`? If so, how many repeaters do you have on your page? Normally, I would just reference `ParentRepeater` directly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What I need from the ParentRepeater is the id of the object from CraftGuides.GetAllGroups(). If that is the same as what you are talking about, can you then make an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Providing that you have a `Group` object, you can use the following:

```
var item = args.Item;
var dataItem = item.DataItem as Group;
```

Then you easily grab the id  of the group object and pass it into your `GetGuidsByGroupID()`.

I like to use the `as` keyword since it will return null if the cast fails. Using `(Group)item.DataItem` would throw an exception if it failed.

Comment: I'm not quite following ya, can you make an example because i'm new to c# ^^

Comment: If I understand your clarification in the comments above, then Digbyswift's example is correct, and that C# code pasted above is what you need.

Comment: I will add, though, that I do not like `as` for the same reason that Digbyswift likes it. I'd rather get the `NullReferenceException` than mysteriously see an empty `Repeater` or get another exception farther away from the source.